# Order of items in the Document Library Bar

Tags: document-library, modern-experience

Is it possible to change the order of the list of feature in this toolbar? I want CopyLink to be replaced by check-out. Sine the copy link feature is not often used I would want Check-in/out feature to be up there in the toolbar for convenience and easier access.

I find it a bit of time consuming having to click at the three dots and then checking in/out files.
[image]